# Rails: how can I access the request object outside a helper or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, helper

In my `application_helper.rb` file I have a function like this:

```
def internal_request?
  server_name = request.env['SERVER_NAME']
  [plus more code...]
end
```

This function is needed in controllers, models, and views. So, I put this code in a utility function file in the `lib/` directory. However, this did not work: I got complaints about `request` not being defined.

How can I access the `request` object in a file in the `lib/` directory?

Comment: The issue is more about putting code in only place. I have a function that uses the request object. This function is used in views and controllers. I can duplicate the code in both places, but it seems cleaner to put the code in the lib/ directory so that both views and controllers can access the single function.

Comment: Your question was already my answer... The request object can be accessed from a helper. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing that would seem to work here is to pass the request object to the method.

```
def internal_request?(request)
 server_name = request.env['SERVER_NAME']
 [plus more code...]
end
```

The assumption is when ever this method is being called a request has been made, and that you can pass it to the method.

I am trying to think of a scenario where a model would need to call this method directly. Seems more likely that you might want to check if this was an internal_request in your controller (mark it as a helper_method in your controller if you need it in your view), and then tell your model it was an internal_request.

Comment: Would prefer an answer that allows direct instantiation of the Rack Request object...

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594467) accomplishes this via a generalized method