# Access request object in rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application_helper.rb file I have a function like this:

```
def find_subdomain
  request.domain
end
```

```
undefined local variable or method `request'
```

And I am invoking this method in another helper. How can i get the domain in helper without passing any argument from controller.

Comment: is a helper supposed to be aware of the `request`?

Comment: `request` is available in helper. Can you show us how you define class for this helper?

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576725/rails-how-can-i-access-the-request-object-outside-a-helper-or-controller

Comment: You can always use `controller.request` but just `request` should be fine. At least in Rails 4.

Comment: when i am calling this method from controller it works calm, but when i invoke this method in another helper it gives me error.

Comment: looks like it depends from where you are invoking the helper method which have request object. If we invoke from controller it's working not from helper.

Comment: pass the `request` object as a method parameter.

Comment: that make sense but the another helper have sub class in that sub class method want to access the find_subdomain. helper sub class doesn't know the request object. I knew its weird design.

Comment: Can't reproduce this in Rails 3.2. `request` works fine from a helper method.

Comment: Though it seems like your code should be working, it's a much better design to explicitly pass the request object into you view helper.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but having stumbled across this myself recently I thought I'd chip in. You could add the method to your `ApplicationController` and specify it as a `helper_method` instead:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :find_subdomain

  private

  def find_subdomain
    request.domain
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the request object should be passed to your helper, which would let you pass it from the view (ERB) as follows,

```
<%= find_subdomain(request) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

helper :all

end