# How to access to 'current_user' outside of controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access to the `current user` outside of a controller and outside of a model. This is the architecture of the project

```
main_engine
|_bin
|_config
|_blorgh_engine
    |_ —> this where devise is installed
|
|_ blorgh2_engine
    |_app
        |_assets
        |_models
        |_assets
        |_queries
            |_ filter_comments.rb -> Where I want to use current_user
```

---

```
 module Blorgh2
    # A class used to find comments for a commentable resource
    class FilterComments < Rectify::Query
      # How to get current_user here ?
    ...
    end
 end
```

I don't think there is a way to do it. If you have an idea, you are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the engine is running in the same thread then perhaps you could store the current_user in the Thread.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_action :store_current_user

  def store_current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user] = current_user
    yield
    ensure
    Thread.current[:current_user] = nil
  end

end
```

Then in your `filter_comments.rb` you can define a method

```
def current_user
  Thread.current[:current_user]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `current_user` variable is tied to the current request, and thus controller instance. In this case you should probably just [parameterize your query](https://github.com/andypike/rectify#passing-data-to-query-objects) with the user you want to filter for:

```
class FilterComments < Rectify::Query
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def query
    # Query that can access user
  end
end
```

Then, in your controller:

```
filtered_comments = FilterComments.new(current_user)
```

This makes it clear where it's coming from, allows you to reuse it with any user, and makes the query object testable, since you can just pass in any user in your test setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My engine doesn't have any controllers . The request is passing through an API then render with react

Answer (score 1):

In my apps, I'm using  variables that scoped to the thread currently executing. This is Rails 5 feature, and it really helping with such out of scope situations.

Idea in this [blogpost](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/09/05/rails-5-adds-ability-to-create-module-and-class-level-variables-on-per-thread-basis.html).

Realisation based on [Module#thread_mattr_accessor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/Module%3Athread_mattr_accessor)

Here example of code.

```rb
class AuthZoneController < ApplicationController
  include Current

  before_action :authenticate_user
  around_action :set_current_user

  private

  def set_current_user
    Current.user = current_user
    yield
  ensure
    # to address the thread variable leak issues in Puma/Thin webserver
    Current.user = nil
  end

end


# /app/controllers/concerns/current.rb
module Current
  thread_mattr_accessor :user
end
```

Now you can access **Current.user** in your current thread in all application scope.